# image analysis : separating intersecting spaghettis

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, lines

I've got an image which to the human eye clearly contains several (2 here) overlapping 'laces'.[image]

This stems from a pretty lengthy image analysis of an experiment.

The red dots are all the points contained in two vectors, px and py, one with the x_position of the red pixels, the other one with the y positions.

```
  px= array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,
     2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,
     3,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   5,   5,   5,   5,   5,
     5,   5,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   7,   7,   7,   7,
     7,   7,   7,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   9,   9,
     9,   9,   9,   9,   9,   9,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
    11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,  12,  12,  12,  12,  12,  12,
    13,  13,  13,  13,  13,  13,  14,  14,  14,  14,  14,  14,  14,
    15,  15,  15,  15,  15,  15,  15,  15,  16,  16,  16,  16,  16,
    16,  16,  16,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  18,  18,  18,  18,
    18,  18,  18,  19,  19,  19,  19,  19,  19,  19,  20,  20,  20,
    20,  20,  20,  20,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  21,  22,  22,
    22,  22,  22,  22,  22,  23,  23,  23,  23,  23,  23,  23,  23,
    24,  24,  24,  24,  24,  24,  24,  24,  25,  25,  25,  25,  25,
    25,  25,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  26,  27,  27,  27,  27,
    27,  27,  27,  28,  28,  28,  28,  28,  28,  28,  29,  29,  29,
    29,  29,  29,  29,  30,  30,  30,  30,  30,  30,  30,  30,  31,
    31,  31,  31,  31,  31,  31,  31,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,
    32,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  34,  34,  34,  34,  34,
    34,  34,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  36,  36,  36,  36,
    36,  36,  37,  37,  37,  37,  37,  37,  37,  38,  38,  38,  38,
    38,  38,  38,  39,  39,  39,  39,  39,  39,  39,  40,  40,  40,
    40,  40,  40,  40,  41,  41,  41,  41,  41,  41,  41,  41,  42,
    42,  42,  42,  42,  42,  42,  43,  43,  43,  43,  43,  43,  43,
    44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  45,  45,  45,  45,  45,
    45,  45,  45,  45,  45,  45,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,
    46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  46,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,
    47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  47,  48,  48,
    48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,  48,
    48,  48,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,
    49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,
    50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,
    50,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,
    51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  51,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,
    52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,  52,
    52,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,
    53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  53,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,
    54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,  54,
    54,  54,  54,  54,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,
    55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,  55,
    55,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,
    56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,  56,
    57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,
    57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  57,  58,  58,  58,
    58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,
    58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  58,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,
    59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,  59,
    59,  59,  59,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,
    60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,
    61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,
    61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  61,  62,  62,  62,
    62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,
    62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  62,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,
    63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  63,
    63,  63,  63,  63,  63,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,
    64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,  64,
    64,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,
    65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  66,  66,
    66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,
    66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  66,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,
    67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,
    67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  67,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,
    68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  68,
    68,  68,  68,  68,  68,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,
    69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,  69,
    69,  69,  69,  69,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,
    70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,  70,
    71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  71,
    71,  71,  71,  71,  71,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,
    72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  72,  73,  73,  73,
    73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,
    73,  73,  73,  73,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,
    74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  74,  75,
    75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,
    75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  75,  76,  76,  76,
    76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,
    76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,  76,
    77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,
    77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,
    77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  77,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,
    78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,
    78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,  78,
    78,  78,  78,  78,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,
    79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,
    79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,
    79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79,
    79,  79,  79,  79,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,
    80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,
    80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,
    80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,
    80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  80,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,
    81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,
    81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,
    81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,
    81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,  81,
    81,  81,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,
    82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,
    82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,
    82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,
    82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  82,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,
    83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,
    83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,
    83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,
    83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  83,  84,  84,  84,  84,
    84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,
    84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,
    84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,  84,
    84,  84,  84,  84,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,
    85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,
    85,  85,  85,  85,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,
    86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  86,  87,  87,
    87,  87,  87,  87,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  89,  89,  89,
    89,  89,  89,  89,  90,  90,  90,  90,  90,  90,  91,  91,  91,
    91,  91,  91,  91,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  93,  93,
    93,  93,  93,  93,  93,  94,  94,  94,  94,  94,  94,  95,  95,
    95,  95,  95,  95,  96,  96,  96,  96,  96,  96,  97,  97,  97,
    97,  97,  97,  97,  98,  98,  98,  98,  98,  98,  99,  99,  99,
    99,  99,  99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101,
   101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103,
   103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105,
   106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107,
   108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109,
   110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111,
   112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114,
   114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116,
   116, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118,
   118, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120,
   120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 122, 122,
   122, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124,
   124, 124, 124, 124, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 126,
   126, 126, 126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128,
   128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 130,
   130, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132,
   132, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 134, 134,
   134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136,
   136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 138,
   138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140,
   140, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142,
   142, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144,
   144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146,
   146, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148,
   149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150,
   151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153,
   153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 155,
   155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 157,
   157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 158, 158, 158, 158, 158, 158, 158, 159,
   159, 159, 159, 159, 159, 159, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160,
   161, 161, 161, 161, 161, 161, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162,
   163, 163, 163, 163, 163, 163, 163, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164,
   164, 165, 165, 165, 165, 165, 165, 165, 165, 166, 166, 166, 166,
   166, 166, 166, 166, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 168, 168,
   168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 170,
   170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 171, 171, 171, 171, 171, 171, 171,
   172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 173, 173, 173, 173])
```

and

```
py=array([189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195,
   190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195,
   196, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196,
   197, 198, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 194, 195, 196, 197,
   198, 199, 200, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 195, 196,
   197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202,
   197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203,
   199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205,
   199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
   205, 206, 207, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 202, 203, 204, 205,
   206, 207, 208, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 204, 205, 206,
   207, 208, 209, 210, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 206, 207,
   208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213,
   207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212,
   213, 214, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 210, 211, 212, 213,
   214, 215, 216, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 211, 212, 213,
   214, 215, 216, 217, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 213,
   214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219,
   220, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,
   221, 222, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 218, 219, 220, 221,
   222, 223, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 219, 220, 221, 222,
   223, 224, 225, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 221, 222, 223,
   224, 225, 226, 227, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 222,
   223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229,
   224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 311, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229,
   230, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231,
   307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
   231, 232, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 227, 228,
   229, 230, 231, 232, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312,
   313, 314, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306,
   307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233,
   234, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311,
   312, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303,
   304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235,
   296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308,
   309, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298,
   299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235,
   236, 237, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301,
   302, 303, 304, 305, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 288,
   289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301,
   302, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 285, 286, 287, 288,
   289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301,
   234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288,
   289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 235, 236, 237,
   238, 239, 240, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290,
   291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241,
   278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290,
   291, 292, 293, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 276, 277, 278,
   279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291,
   237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278,
   279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 238, 239, 240,
   241, 242, 243, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278,
   279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243,
   244, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278,
   279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 265, 266,
   267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279,
   280, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266,
   267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 240, 241,
   242, 243, 244, 245, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266,
   267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245,
   246, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266,
   267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247,
   252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264,
   265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 249, 250,
   251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
   264, 265, 266, 267, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250,
   251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
   243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255,
   256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247,
   248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 235, 236, 237,
   238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250,
   251, 252, 253, 254, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239,
   240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 227,
   228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
   241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 223, 224, 225,
   226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238,
   239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251,
   215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227,
   228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
   241, 242, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214,
   215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227,
   228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 246, 247,
   248, 249, 250, 251, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197,
   198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210,
   211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223,
   224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 247, 248,
   249, 250, 251, 252, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191,
   192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
   205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
   218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
   247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178,
   179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191,
   192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
   205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
   218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 248, 249, 250, 251,
   252, 253, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178,
   179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191,
   192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
   205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
   218, 219, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171,
   172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184,
   185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197,
   198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210,
   211, 212, 213, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 167, 168, 169, 170,
   171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183,
   184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196,
   197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 250, 251,
   252, 253, 254, 255, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175,
   176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 250, 251,
   252, 253, 254, 255, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176,
   177, 178, 179, 180, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 251, 252,
   253, 254, 255, 256, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 252, 253, 254,
   255, 256, 257, 258, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 253, 254, 255,
   256, 257, 258, 259, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 254, 255,
   256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 256, 257,
   258, 259, 260, 261, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 256, 257, 258,
   259, 260, 261, 262, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 258, 259, 260,
   261, 262, 263, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 259, 260, 261, 262,
   263, 264, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264,
   265, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266,
   261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267,
   262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268,
   263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269,
   265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 266,
   267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 267, 268,
   269, 270, 271, 272, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 268, 269,
   270, 271, 272, 273, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 269, 270,
   271, 272, 273, 274, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 270, 271,
   272, 273, 274, 275, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 271, 272,
   273, 274, 275, 276, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 272, 273,
   274, 275, 276, 277, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 273, 274, 275,
   276, 277, 278, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 274, 275, 276,
   277, 278, 279, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 275, 276, 277,
   278, 279, 280, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 276, 277, 278,
   279, 280, 281, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 277, 278, 279,
   280, 281, 282, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 278, 279, 280, 281,
   282, 283, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283,
   284, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284,
   285, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285,
   286, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286,
   287, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288,
   284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290,
   285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 286,
   287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 287,
   288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 289,
   290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 290,
   291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297,
   292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298,
   293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299,
   300, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 295, 296, 297, 298,
   299, 300, 301, 302, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 297, 298,
   299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 299,
   300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306,
   301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 302, 303, 304, 305])
```

To reproduce the image, this MWE should be enough, once you copy-paste the arrays as px and py into your editor

```
import numpy as np
plot_mtx = np.zeros( (5120,5120) )
px=...
py=...
window_size = max(px[-1]-px[0],[py[-1]-py[0]])
imshow(plot_mtx[min(px):min(px)+window_size,min(py):min(py)+window_size])
```

Essentially, these are two lines that each have a width of about 6 pixels. I would like to separate them into two distinct lines, so that I would have px_1,py_1 for the one running from top to down, and px_2,py_2 for the one running from left to right.

I've failed so far to find the right keywords to find such algorithms. What I would have in mind is a for loop, that starts at one extremity, to complete a list with pixel positions in such a way, that the direction in which the loop is progressing never exceeds a certain angle with respect to several previous steps. This way, the algorithm would always take the set of pixels that cross smoothly through the intersection. Then it's just a matter of removing the new found line from the data and starting again.

Would you have any better input ?

Any feedback appreciated

Comment: Minor comment - Your coordinates for `px` and `py` don't match up with the image that is produced.  For one thing, you have `y` coordinates that go beyond 175 but the image stops at 175.

Comment: ah sorry. I had to cut the vectors down if I wanted to post them. Anyway these two vectors should give a relatively similar image.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Skeletonize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) the image.
2. Split by the crossing point(it has more than 2 neighbours) - that gives you 4 segments.
3. Join similarly directed pairs together - you get 2 skeleton lines.
4. Assign original pixels to each of those lines by proximity threshold.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about skeletonize. I'll try it out immediately and get back to you

Comment: @Mathusalem - Look at `scikit-image` for a good out of the box skeletonization algorithm:  http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_skeleton.html